# Не могу записать юзера в текстовый документ

Tags: python, функции, telebot

У меня есть такой фрагмент кода:

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=["start","help","info","hi",'hello','привет'])
def welcome(message): #приветствие
    global users_db
    users_db = open("users.txt", "r")
    global JoinedUser
    JoinedUser = set()
    for line in users_db:
        JoinedUser.add(line.strip())
    if not str(message.chat.id) in users_db:
        users_db = open("users.txt", "a")
        users_db.write(str(message.chat.id) + "\n")
        users_db.add(message.chat.id)
        users_db.close()
    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
    mrk = types.KeyboardButton("Игры")
    mrk1 = types.KeyboardButton("Офисные продукты")
    about_me = types.KeyboardButton("О проекте")
    markup.add(mrk,mrk1,about_me)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id,"Добро пожаловать, {0.first_name}!\nЯ - <b>{1.first_name}</b>, бот для покупки софта, игр и различных подписок на разные сервисы".format(message.from_user, bot.get_me()),parse_mode='html',reply_markup=markup)
@bot.message_handler(commands=['рассылка'])
def news(message):
    for user in users.db:
        bot.send_message(JoinedUser, message.text[message.text.find(' '):])
```

Я пробовал разные способы, но вот все равно на строке `for user in users.db` python не видит переменную `users.db`
Что можно сдлеать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Банально запутался в переменных.
Верный код:

```
users_db = open("users.txt", "r")
JoinedUser = set()
for line in users_db:
    JoinedUser.add(line.strip())
users_db.close()
@bot.message_handler(commands=["start"])
def welcome(message):
    if not str(message.chat.id) in JoinedUser:
        users_db = open("users.txt", "a")
        users_db.write(str(message.chat.id) + "\n")
        users_db.close()
    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
    mrk = types.KeyboardButton("Игры")
    mrk1 = types.KeyboardButton("Офисные продукты")
    about_me = types.KeyboardButton("О проекте")
    markup.add(mrk,mrk1,about_me)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id,"Добро пожаловать, {0.first_name}!\nЯ - <b>{1.first_name}</b>, бот для покупки софта, игр и различных подписок на разные сервисы".format(message.from_user, bot.get_me()),parse_mode='html',reply_markup=markup)
@bot.message_handler(commands=['new'])
def news(message):
    for user in JoinedUser:
        bot.send_message(user, message.text[message.text.find(' '):])
```

Answer (score 0):

Я так думаю вам не стоит использовать глобальные переменные. Лучше вынесете переменные users_db и JoinedUser к импортам. Приведу пример.

```
import time #импорт для примера

users_db = None

JoinedUser = None
```

И помните глобальные переменные это зло

Comment: И ещё я только что заметил то что вы написали users.db, а не users_db. Вы не можете использовать точки в названии переменных. Если вы имели ввиду users_db, а не users.db, то заметите "проблемный" фрагмент кода

Comment: благодарю.  Я написал вот так:

   ```users_db = None
    users_db = open("users.txt", "r")
    JoinedUser = None
    JoinedUser = set()
    for line in users_db:
        JoinedUser.add(line.strip())
    if not str(message.chat.id) in users_db:
        users_db = open("users.txt", "a")
        users_db.write(str(message.chat.id) + "\n")
        users_db.add(message.chat.id)
        users_db.close()```

И появляется ошибка: 

```line 40, in welcome
    users_db.add(message.chat.id)
AttributeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'add'```

Comment: + ко всему я исправил проблемное название, но у меня от этого ```users_db``` и ```JoinedUser``` не перестали выделятся красным